# Java RSA encryption not working when using .NET RSAKeyValue XML string

Tags: java, .net, encryption, rsa

I have the following RSA XML string from a .NET web service

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>+Tir6+unMOaQ5tHqjjjwnlAMhccnCSMFEi3a0mhIxbW+O/GukjomGyzckQT2h0Ys70JezHbNq5YS3sYkNF29kCkz4HuNfy9eEjE/clA9/zyfT8ZcbnusLcLz2xNgbTp62fQdzBnReI5+dpj/N24krYvHaYIr8ACxDqBv2TR3E9M=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

When I use this to do RSA encryption in java I get the following error back from their web service

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Response Code: 100 Message: Invalid authentication credentials ---> Exception of type 'Capita.HSE.GS.Entities.Exceptions.NotificationException' was thrown.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy32.checkEngineerDetailSecure(Unknown Source)
at TestWebService.main(TestWebService.java:98)
```

The strange thing is if they give me an encryoted version of the string I want to encrypt and pass it back to them it works. my code to do the encryption is

```
    private static String rsaEncryptPassword(String modulus, String exponent, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(modulus.getBytes());
    byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(exponent.getBytes());

    BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
    BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusInt, exponentInt);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(cipherData);

    String encryptedString = new String(encryptedBytes);
    System.out.println(encryptedString);

    return encryptedString;
}
```

I'm at a loss from why this is not working after reading all the forms and help sites. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we finally solved the problem. It turns out the the .Net service is using Unicode UTF-16 encoding. So when we get the bytes of the string we had to make it UTF-16. But there is multiple formats for a UTF-16 byte array. There is UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE and UTF-16.

In our case when we converted the string in to a byte array, we had to use UTF-16LE. So in the end, the solution was

```
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

When working with encryption, make sure you know what character encoding the decryption system is using and make sure that that is the character encoding you are using when generating the byte array from the string you want to encrypt.